# Wordpress adds additional year at the end of url even though permalinks settings doesn't have it

Tags: wordpress, redirect, permalinks

I have set my permalinks to "/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/" and at home page when I move cursor to above post link, url is correct. But when I click it, it redirects me to url, which has year at the end. So url "/2013/04/title/" will be redirected to "/2013/04/title/2013/". I tested that it is year by changing year of published post.

I've checked and modified permalinks few times and this still happens. I'm using newest version 3.5.1. It has to be something with wp, because I deactivated all plugins but nothing changed.

Comment: could you provide some kind of link where this problem could be viewed

Comment: Yes, sure. Here's the link http://www.pieceofcode.net/.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be with your theme. Switch to default theme and check whether problem still persists. Your theme might be overriding the URL pattern.

Comment: I'm using the default theme, I also tested with twenty eleven theme which comes with wordpress.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling all plugins? try that out, that may solve your problem.